# Why does my code create a sublist instead of a new element (Python)?

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, append

My code starts with a string that contains a sentence and the category that each word belongs to. Then I store this information in a 2-dimensional list:

```
cadena ="El/DT perro/N come/V carne/N de/P la/DT carnicería/N y/C de/P la/DT nevera/N y/C canta/V el/DT la/N la/N la/N ./Fp"

#convert string into list
cadena_list = []
for i in cadena.split():
    cadena_list.append(i.split("/"))
```

My goal is to store the information in a dictionary, where the key is the word and the value is a two dimensional list that shows to which categories the word belongs and respectively how many times the word occures in the sentence as each category. So e.g. the dictionary entry for the word "la" would look like this: words_categories = {"la", [[DT, 2], ["N", 3]]}.

My code looks like this:

```
#create dictionary that contains the categories and it's respective frequency for ever word
words_categories = {}
for i in range(len(cadena_list)):
    if (cadena_list[i][0] in words_categories):
        l = words_categories[cadena_list[i][0]]
        if (cadena_list[i][1] in l):
            words_categories[cadena_list[i][0]][l.index(cadena_list[i][1]) + 1] += 1
        else:
            words_categories[cadena_list[i][0]].append([cadena_list[i][1], 1])
    else:
        words_categories[cadena_list[i][0]] = [cadena_list[i][1], 1]

print(words_categories["la"])
```

This is the output: ['DT', 2, ['N', 1], ['N', 1], ['N', 1]]
But my goal is this: ['DT', 2], ['N', 3]

Comment: When you run this using a debugger, what is the *first* thing it does wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Welcome!
I believe the root of your issue is here:

```
if (cadena_list[i][1] in l):
    words_categories[cadena_list[i][0]][l.index(cadena_list[i][1]) + 1] += 1
else:
    words_categories[cadena_list[i][0]].append([cadena_list[i][1], 1])
```

The issue is that, in a couple places, you're trying to find the 'category' in a list that doesn't contain categories directly. Take this line for example: `if (cadena_list[i][1] in l)`. `cadena_list[i][1]` is a 'category'  (part of speech?) such as `'DT'` or `'N'`. You're checking if it exists in `l` which is a list which should be of the form `[['DT', 2], ['N', 3]]`. But if this is the case, then `l` definitely doesn't contain `'DT'` or `'N'`; rather it contains sublists containing those elements. Python will always evaluate this expression as false.
Two ideas:

1. You've got a lot of logic going on in single lines of code, and this makes it very easy to make mistakes that are difficult to tease out. Avoid long strings of indices where you can! Instead give names to anything you're going to use more than once, even if it makes your code longer. Allow yourself the luxury of a few more lines if it makes your logic clear; it's not bad programming style.
2. Make `l` a dictionary. You're using it like one, so make it one. The issue I described earlier will go away nicely, because dictionaries elements can be accessed directly by their keys (which is what you're trying to do).

Here's an amended piece of code incorporating both of these suggestions:

```
cadena ="El/DT perro/N come/V carne/N de/P la/DT carnicería/N y/C de/P la/DT nevera/N y/C canta/V el/DT la/N la/N la/N ./Fp"

#convert string into list
cadena_list = []
for i in cadena.split():
    cadena_list.append(i.split("/"))



words_categories = {}
for word, category in cadena_list: # Iterating this way lets you use named variables instead of indexes; less confusing!
    if (word in words_categories):
        l = words_categories[word]
        if (category in l): # This is allowed in a dictionary, but wouldn't work in the list data structure from before
            l[category] += 1 # And this
        else:
            l[category] = 1 #And this
    else:
        words_categories[word] = {category:1} # This is a dictionary instead of a list

print(words_categories["la"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably find this easier to manage with a *defaultdict*

Something like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

cadena = "El/DT perro/N come/V carne/N de/P la/DT carnicería/N y/C de/P la/DT nevera/N y/C canta/V el/DT la/N la/N la/N ./Fp"

outdict = defaultdict(list)

for k, c in [t.split('/') for t in cadena.split()]:
    for e in outdict[k]:
        if e[0] == c:
            e[1] += 1
            break
    else:
        outdict[k].append([c, 1])

print(outdict.get('la'))
```

**Output:**

```
[['DT', 2], ['N', 3]]
```

**Note:**

This is potentially inefficient because of the values being lists of lists. The values should really be a dictionary. That would give  you a [partial] structure like:

```
{
  'la': {
        'DT':2,
        'N': 3
        }
}
```

That would eliminate the need to search and would mean the code could look like:

```
from collections import defaultdict

cadena = "El/DT perro/N come/V carne/N de/P la/DT carnicería/N y/C de/P la/DT nevera/N y/C canta/V el/DT la/N la/N la/N ./Fp"

outdict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))

for k, c in (t.split('/') for t in cadena.split()):
    outdict[k][c] += 1

print(*outdict['la'].items())
```

**Output:**

```
('DT', 2) ('N', 3)
```